# Timer counting not working correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, counting

I’d like to show some text when the player kills e.g. 3, 4, or 5 enemies in a given time (in Unity3d).

I have a timer (comboTimer) which is in my PlayerControl-script that starts when an enemy gets shot by the player. When the timer starts a counter (comboCounter) gets increased everytime an enemy gets shot by the player. The other script (EnemyControl) controls the way how the appropriate text gets displayed when the kill-counter (comboCounter) reaches a certain value (e.g. 3 kills = “Combo x3”). This should be done within the timer’s value.

The problem is the text that gets shown is in almost most cases 3 kills (“Combo x3”). I never reach 4 or 5 kills within the timer’s value even when I increase the waitTime to e.g. 5 or 10 seconds. There is a bug within the logic but can’t find it.

This is the Timer of my PlayerControl-script:

```
public static bool comboTimerRunning = false;
public static int comboCounter;

float comboWaitTime = 1f;//1.0 Sekunden
float comboTimer;

public void ComboTimer() {
    comboTimer += Time.deltaTime;
    if (comboTimer > comboWaitTime) 
    {
        ResetComboTimer();
    }
}

public void ResetComboTimer () {
    comboTimer = 0f;
    comboTimerRunning = false;
    comboCounter = 0;
}
```

This is the script that controls the handling of the displayed text (EnemyControl):

```
if (!PlayerControl.comboTimerRunning) {
        PlayerControl.comboTimerRunning = true;
}
PlayerControl.comboCounter++;
if (PlayerControl.comboCounter >= 3) {
    if (PlayerControl.comboCounter == 3) {
            comboTxtObj.GetComponent<ComboTxt>().ShowComboText("Combo x3");
    } else if (PlayerControl.comboCounter == 4) {
            comboTxtObj.GetComponent<ComboTxt>().ShowComboText("Awesome");
    } else if (PlayerControl.comboCounter >= 5) {
            comboTxtObj.GetComponent<ComboTxt>().ShowComboText("Mega-Kill");
    }
    PlayerControl.comboTimerRunning = false;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the variable `comboTimerRunning`? It is setting to false every time your `comboCounter` reaches 3. So I guess you should check that.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check this out. BTW: The purpose of the variable comboTimerRunning is to check whether to see if the timer is running or not.